# How to upgrade several versions at once?

Tags: upgrade

So today I decided to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 all the way to 13.10, as my laptop has the recommended specs.  I upgraded from 12.04 to 12.10 just fine, but when I upgraded to 13.04, it was 1:50 AM, and I left it running overnight so I could catch some Z's.

When I checked on it this morning, it said that a bunch of errors had occurred, and so I just clicked close.  Then it said it finished the upgrade with some errors, and so I restarted my laptop.  When it booted, it brought me to the system recovery screen, and I did everything available to fix the problems there.

I then restarted my laptop again, but when it booted, it was just a black screen, then became a terminal and nothing more.  I've now erased 13.04 and 12.10 and put 12.04 back on my laptop.  Any ideas/suggestions?

I used the update manager to upgrade distros.  Does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Without knowing what a "bunch of errors" said, it's hard to say what happened.

Comment: I would've posted the error report, but I had no way of doing it other than spending an hour writing it on paper and then on this site.

Comment: search the site for pastebinit

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already erased the operating system, then do a fresh install of the desired Ubuntu version. I have seen Ubuntu fail to upgrade a few times. It is probably some unknown bug.  Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring) is a reliable version, so a fresh install should work well.

Comment: I'm trying the process of upgrading version - by - version again

Comment: If that doesn't work then I'll try simply burning Ubuntu 13.10 ISO to a discount and using it to replace any corrupted OS that might be on my laptop by then.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @battleof3 Why not install 13.10 and not worry about step-installing?

Comment: Whoops, I meant disk, not discount.  Dumb autocorrect.

Comment: Because, I already started upgrading to 12.10, and my other computer is currently in use, so I can't burn an ISO at the moment.

Comment: @battleof3 then wait a moment you can. Upgrading too many versions normally don't go well so the best approach is clean install the OS.